# ¿Cómo redireccionar con PHP teniendo que ejecutar un código para obtener el enlace?

Tags: php

Sé que `header("location:` tiene que estar al principio del código para ejecutarse. Me he incurrido en un problema porque el enlace al qué ese header tiene que ir tiene que generarse antes de disparar el header. Este es mi código (me funcionaba en localhost, pero en producción no va):

```
require_once('../configurationofdatabase.php');
$last_question = $pdo->query("SELECT MAX(product_id) FROM questions ;")->fetchColumn();
$question_id = $last_question + 1;
header("location:../question.php?id=$question_id");
```

Y este es mi archivo configurationofdatabase.php:

```
<?php
# THIS IS THE FILE WHERE WE CONFIGURATE THE CREDENTIALS OF HOSTING CONNECTION

//We determinate the hosting credentials:
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'wlc';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, FALSE);
?>
```

**Edicion**

Si no inluyo las 2 primeras lineas, me funciona:

```
$question_id = 10;
header("location:../question.php?id=$question_id");
```

**Edicion 2**

Si hago un `echo question.php?id=$question_id` desoués de `header("location..` me muestra el enlace correcto. Si dejo `require_once('../configurationofdatabase.php');` no me funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sé que `header("location:` tiene que estar al principio del código para ejecutarse

Esa afirmación no es correcta.

`header` tiene que ser lo primero que se le envía al cliente. Es decir, mientras no le envíes un solo byte al cliente puedes hacer todas las operaciones que consideres oportunas.

Lo único que tienes que garantizar es que no se produzca ningún envío antes de la llamada a `header`.

Otro detalle importante es que después de enviar un `header("location")` **no puedes** enviarle al cliente más datos. Lo más seguro es abortar la ejecución del script después de mandar al cliente una cabecera de redirección.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Pero en configurationofdatabase.php tengo solamente la conección con base de datos y el resto tampoco envío nada al cliente ... ¿qué significa que las rutas sean coincidentes?

Comment: @Lukas Me refiero a que las rutas relativas deben ser coincidentes entre producción y explotación... si no es así (por el motivo que sea) entonces la ruta relativa va a fallar y el navegador no va a redirigir correctamente

Comment: he puesto mi archivo de  configurationofdatabase.php, a lo mejor los comentarios son los que causan el problema? Las rutas son coincidentes en produccion y local... alguna solucion? He comprobado y no se envia nada al cliente .. "Page source" me muestra blanco, sin nada.

Comment: @Lukas si te funciona en localhost entonces no es un problema de envío de datos al cliente... yo miraría el tema de las rutas de los ficheros

Comment: la ruta funciona de esta manera: el archivo question.php?id= al recibir un valor para el ID muestra un contenido u otro. El header simplemente envia al archivo question.php?id= .. y lo demas lo hace el archivo. El acceso al question.php?id= ... funciona, lo he comprobado, las rutas no estan definidas en un archivo aparte.

Comment: @Lukas Recuerda que después de enviar el `header` debes evitar enviar al cliente más información. Lo más seguro en ese caso es abortar la ejecución del PHP

Comment: He mentido, eso era local :D me sigue sin funcionar ... no se que pasa ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57247/discussion-between-lukas-and-eferion).